# objective c inheritance and setter

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, synthesize

Objective C question:

I have a superclass of a ViewController and a superclass of a data controller.  The data controller has delegation to tell the ViewController when it has updated.  It all seems to work, but after putting in some logging it seems that the delegate method is getting called twice every time.  I think I might actually have two instances of every SubDataController.  I must be instantiating something wrong somewhere.  Can anybody see what I am doing wrong??

I have individual screens of a data intensive app.  I have it set up so that there is a superclass of the UIViewController that all inherit from:

DmsProgressBaseViewController.h

```
@class DmsProgressDataController;

@interface DmsProgressBaseViewController : UIViewController

@property(readonly,assign,nonatomic)DmsProgressDataController *dataController;
//index, so we be identified in container
@property(assign,nonatomic)NSInteger index;

@end
```

DmsProgressBaseViewController.m

```
@implementation DmsProgressBaseViewController

@synthesize dataController=_dataController;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(DmsProgressDataController*)dataController
{
    if(!_dataController){
        _dataController=[[DmsProgressDataController alloc]init];
    }
    return _dataController;
}

.....

@end
```

As you can see each view has a datacontroller which loads the data via a rest service and imports it into core data.  It is also inherited from:
DmsProgressDataController.h

```
@class AFHTTPRequestOperation;
@class DmsProgressDataController;

@protocol DmsProgressDataControllerDelegate

-(void)dataLoadedSuccessfully;

@end


@interface DmsProgressDataController : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,assign)id delegate;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *resourceUrl;
-(void)loadDataFromRest;
-(void)loadDataFromRest:(NSString*)resourceUrl;
-(void)handleRestSuccess:(id)jsonResponse;
-(void)handleRestError:(NSError*)error forOperation:(AFHTTPRequestOperation*)operation;

//delegate method
-(void)notifyDataLoadedSuccessfully;

@end
```

DmsProgressDataController.m
    @implementation DmsProgressDataController

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)loadDataFromRest
{
    NSLog(@"loading %@",self.resourceUrl);
    if(self.resourceUrl!=nil){
        [self loadDataFromRest:self.resourceUrl];
    }
}
....

#pragma mark - delegate methods
-(void)notifyDataLoadedSuccessfully
{
    if(self.delegate!=nil){
        [self.delegate dataLoadedSuccessfully];
    }
}
@end
```

So those are the super classes.....

An example of the subclass is:
DmsProgressOverallViewController.h
     @class DmsProgressOverallDataController;

```
@interface DmsProgressOverallViewController : DmsProgressBaseViewController

@property(readonly,strong,nonatomic)DmsProgressOverallDataController *dataController;

@end
```

DmsProgressOverallViewController.m

```
@interface DmsProgressOverallViewController ()<DmsProgressDataControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation DmsProgressOverallViewController
@synthesize dataController=_dataController;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
[self.dataController loadDataFromRest:@"overall"];
    self.dataController.delegate=self;
}

-(DmsProgressDataController*)dataController
{
    if(!_dataController){
        _dataController=[[DmsProgressOverallDataController alloc]init];
    }
    return _dataController;
}
#pragma mark - datacontroller delegate method
-(void)dataLoadedSuccessfully
{
    NSLog(@"Overall data loaded successfully");
}

@end
```

with the datacontroller:

DmsProgressOverallDataController.h

```
@interface DmsProgressOverallDataController : DmsProgressDataController

@end
```

DmsProgressOverallDataController.m

```
@implementation DmsProgressOverallDataController


-(id)init
{
    if(self=[super init]){
        self.resourceUrl=@"progress/totals";
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)handleRestSuccess:(id)jsonResponse
{
    NSString *defaultClg=[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"defaultClg"];
    NSArray *clgs=[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"colleges"];
    for(NSString *clg in clgs){
        College *college =[College MR_createEntity];
        college.collegeName=clg;
        if([defaultClg isEqualToString:clg]){
            college.defaultClg=[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        }
    }

    //DataController delegate method called here
    if(self.delegate!=nil){
        [self.delegate dataLoadedSuccessfully];
    }

}

@end
```

I hope this provides enough information.
Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: I would point out you have convoluted the terminology. `@interface SuperViewController : UIViewController` means that `SuperViewController` is the subclass of `UIViewController`.  `UIViewController` is a subclass of `UIResponder`.  And `UIResponder` is a subclass of `NSObject`, which is the base class.  **EDIT:** i see now that your name of `SuperViewController` is in reference to the `SubViewController` class.

Comment: You need to tell us more about the delegate in question.  We have no information about that.  This is not an inheritance or synthesis problem.

Comment: As other said before, your code is hard to read, since e.g. your SuperViewController is actually a subclass of a UIViewController. And you use a SuperDataController that we don't know.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the vague code. I'm still a stack noob.  I've edited and added more detailed code.  I actually think it <b>is</b> a synthesis/inheritance problem, I'm just not sure how properly do inheritance in objective c.

Answer (score 0):

You have an instance variable name and property name in SubViewController that are also present in the superclass SuperViewController. You synthesize the property name in both the superclass and class. I suspect what is happening is that _dataController in the SubViewClass is the inherited _dataController from SuperViewController. You don't give enough code to see how the dataController is used, but if you had distinct ivar and property names (a) it would be less confusing to read, and (b) it might fix the double call problem. Try it and see!